# What is the "list-separator String appropriate for the host environment’s current locale" in JavaScript (ECMAScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, locale, separator, ecma262

While reading the [ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.tolocalestring), I came across the following step in the `Array.prototype.toLocaleString` method:

> 5. Let *separator* be the String value for the list-separator String appropriate for the host environment’s current locale (this is derived in an implementation-defined way).

My question is, how do we know what is the appropriate list-separator String for the host environment's current locale? Is there any standard for this? Can it be just any string (e.g. "asdfg")?

Comment: The list separator is part of the [locale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software)), specifics depend on the OS. Yes, in theory it can be anything.

Comment: @Bergi I do not understand how the list separator is part of the locale, because I am not familiar with locales. How can I get the list separator of a locale? Can you elaborate on this topic? Thanks.

Comment: A locale is basically just a config file, chosen amongst many by a standardised identifier. These files each contain a definition for a "list separator".

Comment: @Bergi I tried to find these config files and came across this answer for Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423451/388028
I checked the `localedata/locales` directory of glibc and found some variables, such as `decimal_point ","`, but none for a list separator. Do you know where I may find this list-separator string in a locale config file? And is it possible to obtain it with C/C++ code?